# Why would you go to the party without me yesterday

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

I've read on the internet that the phrases "how could someone" and "why would someone" are used in reference to past events. However, nowhere have I seen them used with past time adverbs. So my question is: are these sentences correct with "yesterday"? Or "could"/"would" sound odd with "yesterday"?

1. How **could** you go to the party without me *yesterday*?
2. Why **would** you go to the party without me *yesterday*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.  In formal written English, you might change your examples to the past tense.

> How **could** you **have gone** to the party without me *yesterday*?
>
> Why **would** you **have gone** to the party without me *yesterday*?

The way you wrote them is acceptable too, and probably more common.  Some of the first real-world examples I found: “Why would Germany invade Belgium?” and “Why would Germany support Austria-Hungary?” (I’ve been reading a lot about 1914 lately.)

You’re right, though, that it doesn’t seem to be common to use these modal verbs with adverbs indicating a time in the past.  It’s not something I’ve ever consciously avoided doing, but the closest I found in a quick search was “How could you? Yesterday, you ....”